# Origine du mot "bacaisse"

Tags: étymologie, québec

Le mot *bacaisse* (également orthographié *baquaisse*) désigne au Québec une bâche pour transporter du bois ou une personne corpulente https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacaisse

Y-a-t-il un rapport entre cet ustensile de transport du bois et une personne corpulente, ou bien les deux significations du mot *bacaisse* ont-elles deux origines distinctes ?

Answer (score 1):

En résumé on ne sait pas comment *baquet/bacaisse* a pris le sens de *gros* similairement à *paquet* ni même comment il a pris celui de *bâche* ! On est donc incapable de répondre mais on présente la recherche pour fins de réflexion.

---

Le Wiktionnaire dit « du mot baquet ». Dans le *Glossaire du parler français au Canada* (1930) on ne trouve pas *bacais(se)* mais on trouve bien *baquet, baquèse* (formation surprenante du féminin) pour la « personne grosse et courte » mais pas pour la *bâche* et on réfère au vieux français où ça aurait été un terme de mépris pour *menu, petit* (on ne le trouve pas, on trouve un emploi grivois pour le sexe féminin au [DmF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/baquet?idf=dmfXgXrmXbbbb;str=0)) et on dit ***paquet*** en français. Le [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/25581) contient à l'étymon *bacca* des références à l'auge pour grosses bêtes, des cochons, parfois elle a une forme arrondie, parfois il est fait de bois etc., mais on n'y trouve pas le terme de mépris et au [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/lexique-godefroy/baquet) (Lexique) on trouve *baquier* pour le cochon qu'on engraisse mais ce n'est pas même mot etc. On est incapable d'identifier d'où viendrait le sens de « bâche pour le transport du bois » de *bacaisse/baquet/baquèse*. Peut-être une métonymie du contenant au contenu ? On ne le sait pas.

D'autre part le DHLF indique que c'est par analogie que le *paquet* est attesté pour la personne corpulente en 1803 (ça fait penser à *gros [tas](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tas#Fran%C3%A7ais)*) et on avait le paquet pour l'*affaire encombrante* au 17e (*donner le paquet à qqn.*, éventuellement repris avec *lâcher le paquet* pour *avouer*.).

Answer (score 1):

La bacaisse ou la baquaisse!

Le terme bacaisse est l'un des petits trésors de la langue québécoise. Parlons donc vocabulaire et expression québécoise ! Ce terme très familier n'étant pas univoque, il peut donc signifier plusieurs choses.

L'**orthographie correcte** de ce terme n'est pas "bacaisse" mais bien **"baquaisse"**. Ce nom féminin reste conséquemment lié à son masculin : baquais. Un baquais c'est une personne très corpulente!

Le terme **baquais** est directement connoté aussi au nom baquet qui est pour sa part dérivé du terme latin populaire: baccus (récipient).

> Un bon exemple de la première utilisation (sens premier) de ce nom c'est bien la chanson du groupe de musique québécoise Monoc' Serge qui décrit le contraste saisissant entre la vision contemporaine du corps et celle de nos aïeux.

Toutefois, le terme bacaisse a également un **second sens** qui est plus intimement lié à la culture canadienne et à ses traditions festives !

La baquaisse ou son glissement orthographique bacaisse, est une **bâche** (un morceau de tissus) qui servait à transporter le bois de chauffage dans les maisons canadiennes en période hivernale.

Le nom bacaisse est donc traditionnellement utilisée dans l'expression **Swing la bacaisse dans l'fond d'la boîte à bois.**

Pour pouvoir se joindre à la fête il fallait pouvoir laisser swigner son instrument de travail (bacaisse) dans la boîte à bois pour ainsi se libérer les mains afin de se joindre à la danse  et à la fête rythmée par l'animateur de soirée le calleux !

[Source](http://www.swing-la-bacaisse-dans-lfond-dla-boite-a-bois.com/2013/09/de-kesse-la-bacaisse.html)