# Swing la bacaisse dans l'fond d'la boîte à bois

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, québec

Je voudrais savoir si il existe d'autres interprétations de l'expression «Swing la bacaisse dans l'fond d'la boîte à bois» que celle communément acceptée.

Après avoir lu la question [Origine du mot “bacaisse”](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/36393/22332) je me suis rendu compte que ma définition était différente de celle proposée par Ced dans sa réponse :

> Pour pouvoir se joindre à la fête il fallait pouvoir laisser swinger son instrument de travail (bacaisse) dans la boîte à bois pour ainsi se libérer les mains afin de se joindre à la danse et à la fête rythmée par l'animateur de soirée le calleux !

J'ai toujours pensé que c'était d'avoir des relations intimes avec une petite grosse dans la pièce ou le bois est entreposé. Que c'était la dernière pièce d'une fête réussi. De la danse, des chansons, de la boisson et des gens qui se tripotent dans un petit coin noir.

J'en ai aussi discuté avec une autre personne qui semble penser que c'est de se débarrasser de la petite grosse en question en l'envoyant dans la dite boîte à bois pour pouvoir profiter des festivités sans elle.

Ma question est : Quelle sont les différentes interprétations de cette phrase iconique?

Comment: @un3hiv3r "Le cab du pickup"... drôle de tournure pour vous qui défendez si activement la langue française.

Comment: @LaurentS. Bien vu pour la _caisse_ de la [camionnette](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872572), en fait _cab_ ne désigne pas la caisse mais l'_habitacle_ donc je me suis mal exprimé, merci. Mais dans mon domaine je n'emploie pas de mots étrangers pour chacun des termes consacrés, ni ne serait fier d'en faire la promotion à toutes les occasions. Chez moi la norme veut que quand on fait un CV en français on s'exprime en français, comme on l'explique par exemple [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40733/19187).

Comment: @LaurentS. Bah, j'taime bien, t'as de la gueule. De préférence pour échanger relance-moi chez cosette... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour, je n'ai jamais entendu l'interpretation de la petite grosse...

Le mot bacaisse, pour commenter sur le "confort" d'une femme, oui parfois.  Rarement toutefois.

J'ai entendu cette expression dans des chansons traditionnelles (ex. dans un rigodon) et il était bien compris qu'on y parlait de faire la fête, pas s'envoyer en l'aire avec une toutoune.

Une référence parmis tant d'autres: http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/expression-quebecoise/swing-la-bacaisse-dans-lfond-de-la-boite-bois.html

Mais cette expression n'est pas utilisée courament, si vous lancez ça en publique, attendez-vous a de drôles de regards :-)